# I manually deleted my /etc/php5/ config files and now they don't reinstall

Tags: php, debian, apt, reinstall

I wanted a clean reinstall of `php5-cli`, `php5-common`, `php5-fpm`. So what I did was:

```
rm -rf /etc/php5
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/php5
rm -rf /usr/local/php5
rm -rf /usr/lib/php
apt-get autoremove php5*
apt-get purge php5*
```

But after reinstalling I don't have `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` or `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` anymore. How could I get them back?

My install command:

`apt-get install php5-cli php5-comon php5-cli --force-yes -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confmiss`

Answer (score 4):

First you need to do complete removal of packages using this command.

```
sudo apt-get purge php*
```

Now install again using

```
sudo apt-get install php*
```

You will get generated new config files.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea

Comment: ✅ **It is a good idea**. If you're afraid, maybe you should use server provisioning tools or virtual machines to test commands. `sudo apt-get purge` will remove configurations and next time you install them, default configurations will be created again. Have a look to this great answer if in doubt: https://askubuntu.com/a/187891/172828 The bad idea here is not the `purge` command, it's the part where the *user manually deleted folders* instead of *using the tools provided by the package manager*. 