# Deleted php5 www.conf help please

Tags: php, php-fpm, php5

I accidentally deleted the php5 www.conf file located at:

/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

is there any way to get a copy of the original file back?

I believe there is an answer to my question located here:

[I manually deleted my /etc/php5/ config files and now they don't reinstall](https://serverfault.com/questions/484342/i-manually-deleted-my-etc-php5-config-files-and-now-they-dont-reinstall)

but I currently have a site running on the server, would it not be esaier to simply restore the php5 www.conf file with the original version?

Comment: Well, about the only way you are going to get back a file that you deleted is by extracting it from backups you have made.

Comment: There has to be an easier way, it's a standard unaltered conf file, is there nowhere to aquire an original copy of the www.conf?

Comment: yum reinstall or just download php-fpm package and extract it to get that file.

Comment: @mdpc Nah, it'll be easier to just have puppet replace it from the version-controlled repository, right?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a copy of the default file from an installation of PHP-FPM which I have; http://pastebin.com/Jpm1cBqn